# Argument 'middleController' is not a function, got undefined. Can't find anything in past questions

Tags: angularjs

1. index.html

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   ```

   ```
   <header>
       <h1>DOE</h1>
   </header>
   <div id="selectSchoolText">
       Please select your school.
   </div>

   <div ng-controller="middleController">
       <select class="selectpicker" ng-repeat="school in middleSchools">
           <option>{{ school.name }}</option>
       </select>
   </div>




   <script src="lib/jquery/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/X.Y.Z/angular-route.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/angular/dashboardApp/modulesApp.js"></script>
   <!--<script src="lib/angular/dashboardApp/elementaryController.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/angular/dashboardApp/middleController.js"></script>
   <!--<script src="lib/angular/dashboardApp/highController.js"></script>
   <script src="lib/angular/dashboardApp/otherController.js"></script>-->
   ```
2. moduleApp.js

   var app = angular.module('selectApp', []);

   ```
   app.controller('middleCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.middleSchools = [
           {name: 'Kaimuki Middle'},
           {name: 'Kamakahelei Middle'},
           {name: 'Kapolei Middle'},
           {name: 'Kea\'au Middle'},
           {name: 'Kealakehe Intermediate'},
           {name: 'Moloka\'i Middle'},
           {name: 'Nanakuli High & Intermediate'},
           {name: 'Niu Valley Middle'},
           {name: 'Washington Middle'}
           ];
   });
   ```

I keep receiving the error message "Argument 'middleController' is not a function, got undefined." ...not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<div ng-controller="middleController">`

You called it middleCtrl

`app.controller('middleCtrl', function($scope) {`

Answer (score 0):

your name of controller is not correct its '`middleCtrl`' while in view you have used `middleController`

change it to

```
app.controller('middleController', function($scope) {
...
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

First, you are using a wrong name of the controller in your view `<div ng-controller="middleController">` instead of `<div ng-controller="middleCtrl">`. And second you have to define `ng-app="selectApp"` into your html or body tag or somewhere in your HTML code.